# Loop css background via javascript not working in codepen

Tags: javascript, css, loops

I need to loop through css background-image

Does anyone see why the background isn't changed here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGKYaJ

```
var bg = $('.background').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = bg;
backgrounds[1] = 'https://placehold.it/300x300&text=1';
backgrounds[2] = 'https://placehold.it/300x300&text=2';

function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 2) currentBackground = 0;

    $('.background').fadeOut(3000,function() {
        $('.background').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('.background').fadeIn(3000);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 7000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 7000);        
});
```

Any suggestion's appreciated

ra

Comment: you sure you're not looking for `setInterval` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. this error is thrown in Console :

   ```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
   ```

   You forgot to include the jQuery librery to codpen settings. check
   [this working codepen](http://codepen.io/tunecino/pen/VedeZx).
2. One more issue to solve in line 2 : `bg =
   bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');` need to be replaced by :

   ```
   bg = bg.replace('url(\"','').replace('\")','');
   ```

   otherwise **backgrounds[0]** value will be double quoted
   `""https://...""` which raises a 404 error when tries to load the
   image.

```js
var bg = $('.background').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(\"','').replace('\")','');
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = String(bg);
backgrounds[1] = 'https://placehold.it/300x300&text=1';
backgrounds[2] = 'https://placehold.it/300x300&text=2';


function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 2) currentBackground = 0;

    $('.background').fadeOut(3000,function() {

        $('.background').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('.background').fadeIn(3000);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 7000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 7000);        
});
```

```css
.background
{
  background-image:url("https://placehold.it/300x300&text=original");
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background"></div>
```